# How to add so number to QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVOICE xml request using php webconnector in quickbooks?

Tags: php, xml, quickbooks

I'm using quickbooks desktop enterprise version.

And I want to send invoice from magento to quickbooks using php dev kit with web connector.

In my quickbooks I have template custom S.O invoice.

and I have field called so number.But i'm not able add this field in xml requset.

Please guide me any one for this?

```
$xml = '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="5.0"?>
    <QBXML>
      <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <InvoiceAddRq requestID="'.$requestID.'">
          <InvoiceAdd>
            <CustomerRef>
                <FullName>'.$order['customername'].'</FullName>
            </CustomerRef>
        <TemplateRef> 
      <FullName >Custom S.O. Invoice</FullName> 
      </TemplateRef>
        <TxnDate>'.$order['orderdate'].'</TxnDate>
            <RefNumber>'.$order['realorder_id'].'</RefNumber>
            <BillAddress>
                <Addr1>'.$order['billaddress']['address1'].'</Addr1>
                <Addr2>'.$order['billaddress']['address2'].'</Addr2>
                <City>'.$order['billaddress']['city'].'</City>
                <State>'.$order['billaddress']['state'].'</State>
                <PostalCode>'.$order['billaddress']['postal_code'].'</PostalCode>
                <Country>'.$order['billaddress']['country'].'</Country>
            </BillAddress>
            <ShipAddress>
                <Addr1>'.$order['shipaddress']['address1'].'</Addr1>
                <Addr2>'.$order['shipaddress']['address2'].'</Addr2>
                <City>'.$order['shipaddress']['city'].'</City>
                <State>'.$order['shipaddress']['state'].'</State>
                <PostalCode>'.$order['shipaddress']['postal_code'].'</PostalCode>
                <Country>'.$order['shipaddress']['country'].'</Country>
            </ShipAddress>'; 

for($i=0;$i < $order['itemcount'];$i++){

    $xml .= '<InvoiceLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                    <FullName>'.$order['items']['sku'][$i].'</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>'.$order['items']['name'][$i].'</Desc>
                    <Quantity>'.$order['items']['qty'][$i].'</Quantity>
  <Rate>'.$order['items']['unitPrice'][$i].'</Rate>
                    </InvoiceLineAdd>';
    }

    $xml .= '</InvoiceAdd>
            </InvoiceAddRq>
          </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';
```

Comment: Is your SO # a custom field in QuickBooks?

Comment: yes i think.i'm new to quickbooks.Actually im a magento developer

Comment: I have already sales order in qb.So i want to add invoice for that.So i need to add s.o numaber.please guide me for this